# How to compute sample size to compare two diagnostic tests

Tags: sample-size, diagnostic

I will be performing two diagnostic tests (one is the gold standard, one is novel) on the same subject aiming to establish sensitivity, specificity, PPV and NPV. What formula may be used to compute for a good sample size?

What is better way to establish correlation of the two tests? I understand a Bland-Altman plot may not be used since my tests check for two different parameters (and diagnosis lies on the interpretation of the parameters)?

Comment: Maybe this package can be of help to you:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MKmisc/docs/power.diagnostic.test

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Oystein. At present, this is really more of a comment than an answer. Can you expand on this? Why is that package the right choice for the OP? How would you use it to resolve the OP's problem?